# Java 9+ get module information by annotated module-info

Tags: java, java-module

I created custom annotation named ModuleDescription like this :

```
@Target(ElementType.MODULE)
public @interface ModuleDescription {
    String name();
    double version();
    String description();
}
```

and use this annotation on module-info class :

```
@ModuleDescription(name = "api", version = 1.2, description = "Simple API")
module api {
    exports com.example.api;
}
```

this code load module-info class but i can not found any reference to this annotation :

```
var boot = ModuleLayer.boot();
boot.findModule("api").get()
```

this is project structure :

```
├── api
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               ├── com
│               │   └── example
│               │       └── api
│               │           └── ModuleDescription.java
│               └── module-info.java
├── application
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               ├── com
│               │   └── example
│               │       └── MainClass.java
│               ├── module-info.java
```

How can access to this annotation ?

**Note 1**: Project setup up by maven and compiled without any problem
**Note 2**: java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS

Comment: Is the `api` module part of the boot layer? Try adding `--add-module api` to the command line.

Comment: I dont know , I setup project by maven , and i say module loaded in MainClass . @JohannesKuhn

Comment: Can you access ModuleDescription from your main class?

Comment: No, like `ModuleDescription.class`

Comment: oh , sorry i misunderstood ,yes i access to ModuleDescription.class directly .

Comment: Good. Then try `ModuleDescription.class.getModule().getAnnotation(ModuleDescription.class)`.

Comment: What ?!?! , first : so what happened if i use this annotation on multiple module ? , second: not working !!

Comment: Are you sure your modules are on the module path? What is the output of `System.out.println(ModuleDescription.class.getModule())`?

Comment: A simple "FIXED" is not enough. You should probably write an answer, explaining what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**Fixed**
I forget add `@Retention(RUNTIME)` to annotation .
Thank you `johannes Kuhn`